# What is wrong with my URI path to my video?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some videos I'm trying to display on a contentcontrol. I have this part working.  I have the videos in a local folder (displaying in solution explorer as Video/Start). I am trying to pass the path to the video in the URI format like below:

```
/GCodeConverter;component/Video/Start/Begin.wmv
```

I've tried a bunch of different formats including:

```
pack//GCodeConverter;component/Video/Start/Begin.wmv
```

But I keep getting the error:
"Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."
no matter how I enter it. What should it look like?

Comment: Is it a resource? Did you set its build action to resource?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Pack URIs is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx

I'm assuming your video content is a "content file" rather than a WPF Resource ( in a `*.xaml` file), .NET Resource (in a `.resx` or `.resources` file), or Win32 resource (in a `.res` or `.rc` file). A "content file" is a file in the filesystem of the application, paths are relative to the location of the executable.

...in which case you need to use the `pack://` URI scheme (note the colon, which you omitted) in addition to using the `application;,,,` authority (note the semicolon and three commas, which escape three forward-slashes as per the RFC2396 rules).

```
pack://application;,,,/Video/Start/Begin.wmv
```